# How can I match the shortest string including new lines?

Tags: regular-expression

In search expressions I know I can find the shortest match on line with the following expression:

```
begin.\{-}end
```

So for example, if the text is like this:

```
begin end1 end2 end3
```

Then it will match up to the "1". However, what if the text is spread over multiple lines like this:

```
begin blah blah blah
blah blah blah end1 end2 end3
```

How do I do the same match across the end of line?

Answer (score 2):

try `/begin\_.\{-}end`

`\_.`   Matches any single character or end-of-line.

Comment: See [`:h /\_`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c_)